# Background com imagem transparente

Tags: html, css

Como deixo a imagem de fundo transparente e responsiva, responsiva eu consegui com o código abaixo, mais agora preciso colocar transparecia na imagem.

> CSS

```
body{
  background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover; /*Css padrão*/
  -webkit-background-size: cover; /*Css safari e chrome*/
  -moz-background-size: cover; /*Css firefox*/
  -ms-background-size: cover; /*Css IE não use mer#^@%#*/
  -o-background-size: cover; /*Css Opera*/
}
```

> HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ControlHall - Telve Tecnologia</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o filtro de opacidade no CSS:

```
opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* PARA IE8 ou superiores */
```

Leia mais sobre opacidade e transparência no site do [W3SCHOOLS - CSS Opacity / Transparency](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)